# find average time of day of an event when the time range spans a day

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to determine the average time of the day that a particular event takes place.  For most events, I am able to do this by using the following query:

`SEC_TO_TIME( round( avg( TIME_TO_SEC( TIME(MY_EVENT_TIME) ) ) ),0 )`

Where this logic breaks, is when the time range spans midnight.

Given the following dataset,
21:37:37
22:00:29
23:01:13
23:09:41
23:56:37
00:02:43
00:15:31
01:19:52
02:55:59
04:27:56

I would expect the average time to be somewhere around 00:00:00.

Averaging the UNIX_TIMESTAMP's doesn't help, because that takes into account the dates.

Is there a purely MySQL method to solve this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow.  Given 23:45 and 00:15, I think you'd expect the 'average' time to be 00:00, yes, since that is midway between quarter till midnight and quarter past midnight?  But why isn't 12:00 acceptable, which is also exactly midway between quarter after midnight and quarter till midnight?  What if the dataset was 23:45, 00:15 and 00:16?

Comment: there is no single answer; for instance, if you have times 08:00:00, 09:00:00, 22:00:00, if you think of it in terms of a day that starts at midnight, the average is 13:00:00.  If you think if it in terms of a day that starts at noon, the average is 05:00:00.  Please clarify what you want.

Comment: To make it work, the date is required.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that without a date the events are all happening in the *same day*. Hence you end up with the average being midday and not midnight.

Adding a date to your data gets the correct result. For example

```
create table day_event_log
(
    an_event timestamp not null
);

insert day_event_log(an_event)
values ('2023-01-01 21:37:37'),
       ('2023-01-01 22:00:29'),
       ('2023-01-01 23:01:13'),
       ('2023-01-01 23:09:41'),
       ('2023-01-01 23:56:37'),
       ('2023-01-02 00:02:43'),
       ('2023-01-02 00:15:31'),
       ('2023-01-02 01:19:52'),
       ('2023-01-02 02:55:59'),
       ('2023-01-02 04:27:56');

select time(FROM_UNIXTIME(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(an_event)))) avg_event
from day_event_log;
```

`avg_event = 00:16:45.8000`

Although this explains the reason you are seeing a midday result with the data set you have, as mentioned in the comments it does not solve your problem. Time is continuous, so you have to decide how to partition it and where the "centre" of that time period is in order to calculate an average.

Comment: totally agree, except I think the question is looking for an average time that something happens, irrespective of what day it is (which isn't really a solvable problem, without additional constraints)

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. When the data spans multiple days you would end up with a mid point _across all those days_ :)